# How do I know what I need to show when using induction? (Peano axioms)

Tags: logic, proof-writing, induction, quantifiers, peano-axioms

As an exercise I wanted to prove that addition was commutative using the Peano axioms.

To quickly restate the definition of addition (where $S(n)$ is the successor function of $n$, which we can show is the same as $S(n) = n+1$):

$$\begin{align}
a + 0 &= a \tag{additive identity} \\
a + S(b) &= S(a + b) \tag{addition of naturals} 
\end{align}$$

The axiom of induction then is the statement that:

$$\forall P(P(0) \land (P(k) \implies P(k+1)) \implies \forall n(P(n)))$$

Which means for all predicates, some base case being true and the $k$th case implying the $k+1$th case means that the predicate is true for all $n$.

For the purposes of this question, assume we have just proven that $a + 0 = 0 + a$, that $a + 1 = 1 + a$, and that $(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)$.

Then my question is how we're actually using this induction for proving the general commutative case $a+b=b+a$. Here is what I originally did:

**Base case:** We have $a + 0 = 0 + a$ as true.

**Inductive step**: Suppose $a+b = b+a$. Then $a+S(b) = S(a + b) = S(b + a) = b + S(a) = b + (a + 1) = b + (1 + a) = (b + 1) + a = S(b) + a$. We also have $(b+1)+a = (1+b)+a = 1+(b+a) = 1+(a+b) = (1+a)+b = S(a) + b$.

I figure that $P(0)$ here is when $k=0$ and we say $a+k = k+a$ is our base case, same as how we say $a + 0 = 0 + a$ is our base case.

But then what exactly is the $k+1$th case here? I mean I tried to show that $a+b=b+a$ implied all sorts of identities (I basically tried to sledgehammer it with every permutation I could think of) but I don't know exactly what is minimal and sufficient to prove the inductive step.

If the inductive hypothesis is $a+b=b+a$ and this is our $k$th step, i.e. $P(k)$ is true, what is $k$ here? $k=a$? $k=b$? Is it enough to show that $S(a) + b = b + S(a)$? If not, how do I know what all I must prove here?

I'm trying to stay strict within the definitions here so that I don't run the risk of letting intuition and "common sense" cheat myself of the understanding here.

How do I correctly interpret the $P$ statements here? What is $P(0)$? What is $P(k)$? What is $P(k+1)$ and what must I do to show it? Or is my induction axiom not correct? What should I be doing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We want to prove *commutativity* of sum, i.e.: $m+n=n+m$.

The proof has a first step by *induction* on $n$, and thus the $P(n)$ to be used with induction axioms is:

> $a+n=n+a$.

*(i) Basis*: $a+0=0+a$ ($P(0)$), and

*(ii) Induction step*: assuming that $a+n=n+a$ holds (*induction hypotheses*) we have to prove that $a+s(n) = s(n)+a$.

Having done the two steps of induction, the *Induction axioms* allows to conclude with:

> $\forall n \ (a+n=n+a)$.

The above result has been derived for a "generic" $a$ (for $a$ whatever): thus, we may geenralize it using [Universal generalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization) to conclude with:

> > $\forall m \ \forall n \ (m+n=n+m)$.

Comment: So then was my initial approach overkill? Would it have been enough to show that $a + S(b) = S(a+b) = S(b+a) = b + S(a) = b + (1 + a) = (b + 1) + a = S(b) + a$, and then I'm done?

Comment: @user537069 - you have to use directly the *induction hypotheses* : $a+S(b)=S(a+b)=S(b+a)=S(b)+a$. From left to right: first by sum axiom, second by *ind hyp* and equality axiom, third by sum axioms.

Comment: I don't believe I can jump straight from $S(b+a)$ to $S(b) + a$ since addition is only defined for $a + S(b) = S(a+b)$ at this stage, although proving that addition is commutative would then allow me to use that in the future.

Comment: @user537069 - correct: you have to prove previously (by induction): $s(a)+b=s(a+b)$. For the detailed development of *formal arithmetic* you can see some specific textbook: [Mendelson](https://books.google.it/books?id=FS-sCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA1) and [Kleene (1952)](https://books.google.it/books?id=HZAjPwAACAAJ).

Answer (score 0):

In the vein of my previous answer, here's some Agda:

```
data _≡_ {A : Set} (a : A) : A → Set where
    Refl : a ≡ a

data ℕ : Set where
    Z : ℕ
    S : ℕ → ℕ

_+_ : ℕ → ℕ → ℕ
m + Z = m
m + S n = S (m + n)

cong : {A B : Set} → (f : A → B) → {x y : A} → x ≡ y → f x ≡ f y
cong f Refl = Refl

_trans_ : {A : Set} → {x y z : A} → x ≡ y → y ≡ z → x ≡ z
Refl trans q = q

left-additive-identity : {n : ℕ} → (Z + n) ≡ n
left-additive-identity {Z} = Refl
left-additive-identity {S n} = cong S (left-additive-identity {n})

left-increment : {m n : ℕ} → (S m + n) ≡ S (m + n)
left-increment {m} {Z} = Refl
left-increment {m} {S n} = cong S (left-increment {m} {n})

commutative : {m n : ℕ} → (m + n) ≡ (n + m)
commutative {Z} {n} = left-additive-identity {n}
commutative {S m} {n} = left-increment {m} {n} trans cong S (commutative {m} {n})
```

This uses the equivalent of three uses of the induction axiom. One each for `left-additive-identity` which proves that $0+n=n$ ($n+0=n$ comes automatically from the definition of `_+_`); `left-increment` which proves $(m+1)+n=(m+n)+1$; and commutativity itself. `Refl` represents reflexivity of equality. `cong` represents the congruence property of equality, i.e. that functions take equal inputs to equal outputs. This is only used in the form: if $m=n$, then $m+1=n+1$. `trans` is the transitivity of equality.